# How to declare a JSON and iterate through it?

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON has a collection of three array objects. Where each array in itself is a collection of three other objects,in total there are nine objects.
this is my JSON :

```
{
           "image1" :  [{
                "id": "table",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/table.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Tables are needed for maintaining a good posture and consequently, \n good health - an entrepreneur cant function with a perpetually aching \n back now, can he?"           
            }, {
                "id": "computer",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/computer.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Whats work without a computer?"
            }, {
                "id": "ac",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/ac.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Air cons are luxuries. Besides, \nas an entrepreneur, \nyoure supposed to be sweating it out!"
            }],

            "image2" :  [{
                "id": "sofa",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/sofa.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Sofas are a luxury. Besides, \nstartups are all but cozy and cusiony, like a sofa!"

            }, {
                "id": "xbox",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/xbox.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Gaming in the office space is a strict no-no.\n For an entrepreneur, work itself is play!"
            }, {
                "id": "whiteboard",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/whiteboard.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Wall emulsion paint turns all your walls\n into gigantic whiteboards. So why waste money \non a small one?"
            }],

            "image3" : [{
                "id": "pool",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/pooltable.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Pool-dreams are to be dreamt after your startup grows."
            }, {
                "id": "green",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/inofficeplant.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Landscaping in the office?\n Lifes not a golf course - especially \nfor a startup."
            }, {
                "id": "paper",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/paper.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Be a jugaadu and improvise to save costs \n- why would you want to buy paper when you can use the empty side\n of election pamphlets?"
            }]

}
```

Now I want to access source and id of each image object, like of 'table' or 'ac'. The problem is its giving image object as `i`.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
for(var rowCtr in a.imageTable){
                var obj=rowCtr;
                for(var colCtr =0;colCtr<obj.length;colCtr++){

                    var imageObject = obj[colCtr];
```

imageTable is the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `for (variable in object)`, it sets `variable` to the keys of the object, not the values. To access the values, you have to use `object[variable]`. So in your case, it should be:

```
for (var rowCtr in a.imageTable) {
    var obj = a.imageTable[rowCtr];
```

Comment: thanks! it solved my problem can you please elaborate the explanation?

Comment: I'm not sure what more to say about it. On the first iteration, `rowCtr` will be `image1`, next time it will be `image2`, and so on. To access the arrays in those properties, you have to use `a.imageTable[rowCtr]`.

Answer (score 0):

if a variable `imageTable` refers to the json as posted, you would iterate over the array containing objects with an `id` like this:

```
var array = imageTable.image1; // or image2, image3
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    console.log(array[i].id); //  wil output table, computer, ac
}
```

```js
var imageTable = {
           "image1" :  [{
                "id": "table",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/table.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Tables are needed for maintaining a good posture and consequently, \n good health - an entrepreneur cant function with a perpetually aching \n back now, can he?"           
            }, {
                "id": "computer",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/computer.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Whats work without a computer?"
            }, {
                "id": "ac",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/ac.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Air cons are luxuries. Besides, \nas an entrepreneur, \nyoure supposed to be sweating it out!"
            }],

            "image2" :  [{
                "id": "sofa",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/sofa.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Sofas are a luxury. Besides, \nstartups are all but cozy and cusiony, like a sofa!"

            }, {
                "id": "xbox",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/xbox.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Gaming in the office space is a strict no-no.\n For an entrepreneur, work itself is play!"
            }, {
                "id": "whiteboard",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/whiteboard.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Wall emulsion paint turns all your walls\n into gigantic whiteboards. So why waste money \non a small one?"
            }],

            "image3" : [{
                "id": "pool",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/pooltable.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Pool-dreams are to be dreamt after your startup grows."
            }, {
                "id": "green",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/inofficeplant.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Landscaping in the office?\n Lifes not a golf course - especially \nfor a startup."
            }, {
                "id": "paper",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/paper.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Be a jugaadu and improvise to save costs \n- why would you want to buy paper when you can use the empty side\n of election pamphlets?"
            }]

};

var array = imageTable.image1; // or image2, image3
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    console.log(array[i].id); //  wil output table, computer, ac
}
```

You can expand this to iterate over all of the `imageX` objects with a nested loop

```
var keys = Object.keys(imageTable);
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    var array = imageTable[keys[i]];
    for(var j=0;j<array.length;j++){
        console.log(array[j].id); //  wil output table, computer, ac, sofa, xbox etc
    }
}
```

```js
var imageTable = {
           "image1" :  [{
                "id": "table",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/table.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Tables are needed for maintaining a good posture and consequently, \n good health - an entrepreneur cant function with a perpetually aching \n back now, can he?"           
            }, {
                "id": "computer",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/computer.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Whats work without a computer?"
            }, {
                "id": "ac",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/ac.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Air cons are luxuries. Besides, \nas an entrepreneur, \nyoure supposed to be sweating it out!"
            }],

            "image2" :  [{
                "id": "sofa",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/sofa.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Sofas are a luxury. Besides, \nstartups are all but cozy and cusiony, like a sofa!"

            }, {
                "id": "xbox",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/xbox.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Gaming in the office space is a strict no-no.\n For an entrepreneur, work itself is play!"
            }, {
                "id": "whiteboard",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/whiteboard.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Wall emulsion paint turns all your walls\n into gigantic whiteboards. So why waste money \non a small one?"
            }],

            "image3" : [{
                "id": "pool",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/pooltable.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Pool-dreams are to be dreamt after your startup grows."
            }, {
                "id": "green",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/inofficeplant.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Landscaping in the office?\n Lifes not a golf course - especially \nfor a startup."
            }, {
                "id": "paper",
                "source": "http://test.reinventio.tk/office-space-game-3/images/paper.jpg",
                "alert": [],
                "explanation": "Be a jugaadu and improvise to save costs \n- why would you want to buy paper when you can use the empty side\n of election pamphlets?"
            }]

};

var keys = Object.keys(imageTable);
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    var array = imageTable[keys[i]];
    for(var j=0;j<array.length;j++){
        console.log(array[j].id); //  wil output table, computer, ac, sofa, xbox etc
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to iterate over all the images, not just `imageTable.image1`.

Comment: yes, i don't want to select it myself,i want it to iterate through all the images

Comment: what does `Object` function does?

Comment: @FossArduino its just slightly neater than `for...in` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can access to the id and source of each opicture

```
var id = []; 
var src= [];
for (var rowCtr in a.imageTable) {
        id= a.imageTable[rowCtr].id;
        src= a.imageTable[rowCtr].source;
}
```